# Norm on a module over an ordered ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request

The definition of [norm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_%28mathematics%29) defined satisfies positive homogenity, triangle inequality, and separation of points.

Now, suppose, I have a module $M$ over an ordered ring $R$ where $R$ is endowed with an [absolute value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value_%28algebra%29) and is an ordered ring. Technically, I can still define a notion of norm on $M$ as a function from $M$ to $R$ satisfying the above properties (or replacing the triangle inequality by the ultra-metric one depending on the absolute value).

I was wondering, if such a general notion has been studied and if so, can someone point me to some references.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi - I'm a bit confused since your ring has both an absolute value and an ordering?  Do they need to be compatible?